# Checking if digits in a string are symmetric (in edges)

Tags: c, string, recursion, palindrome

I have a string of numbers. I need to check if the numbers on the edges are symmetric, meaning they have the same remainder when modulo by 2.

I have written a code which works, but I have something troubling my mind about that, after some failures I've come up with this code:

```
int PaliPair(char* st, int n)
{
  if(n<=1) return 1;
  return (*st%2 == *(st+n-1)%2) && PaliPair(st +1, n-2);
}
```

The question is, why do I have to return `n-2` and not `n-1`? I'm kinda confused of why it works. Any explanation would be highly appreciated. I think I'm missing something, perhaps the fact that the string ends with `"\0"` which I need to conclude from that something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a string for example like this

```
"1243"
```

then you at first check the first and the last characters.

Then you need to check the characters in the middle that is

```
"24"
```

So the target string now has length 4 - 2 (the number of characters that were already checked)

So in each recursion you check 2 characters, In the next recursion you need to check 2 less characters.

As for the function itself I would write it like

```
int PaliPair( const char *s, size_t n )
{
   return n < 2 || *s % 2 == *( s + n - 1 ) % 2 && PaliPair( s + 1, n - 2 );
}
```

Or even like

```
int PaliPair( const char *s, size_t n )
{
   return n < 2 || ( *s - '0' ) % 2 == ( *( s + n - 1 ) - '0' ) % 2 && PaliPair( s + 1, n - 2 );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Suppose your string is `21312`, at first step you will compare 2 and 2 from both ends. Then you go one step forward with `st+1` you should consider `131`, so you should not consider `2`'s from beginning and the end of your string, that's why you do `n-2`.

In this way you go one character forward from beginning of the string but you should also shift one character backward from the end of the string as well.
I hope you get my point.